# OpenCV assertion failed in LocateROI

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, osx-leopard, assertion

I'm having a problem with an OpenCV program which compiles correctly but when it runs it aborts giving this error:

```
    OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0) in locateROI, file /home/user/Desktop/HOME/src/OpenCV/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 647
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/user/Desktop/HOME/src/OpenCV/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:647: error: (-215) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function locateROI

Aborted
```

I'm using ubuntu with the latest OpenCV libraries but it gives me the same error also on Leopard with Eclipse.

The matrix.cpp file is inside my OpenCV source folder.

I'm not able to understand why I'm getting this error.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In order for anyone to help, we need to see your code. My best guess, the error is most likely that you are selecting a region of interest in an image that does not fit inside that image. Happens to me all the time. Are you using the latest as in the svn version, or version 2.2 precompiled on the website?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code seems that you have

> not enough dimensions: dims <= 2
>
> and of course the length of a single row is zero step[0] > 0

How are you creating the ROI ? Can you post  a code Snip ?